# current_user not accessible in Batch_Action form block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan

Trying to access **current_user** in `form` block of **batch_action** as follows:

```
batch_action 'Change Status', confirm: 'Mass-Assign Status', 
form: {'Location' => City.where(:company_id => current_user.company_id).map{|s| [s.to_s, s.id]}} 
do |selection, inputs|
    //---- Code ----- (current_user can be accessed over here successfully)
end
```

Error that I receive is `undefined local variable or method current_user for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x00007f814b3e0db8> (NameError)`

But I can easily access current_user inside the do-end block.

- Ruby version: 2.5.5p157
- Rails version: 4.2.11.1
- ActiveAdmin

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable is not accessible in this context.

Try to make it global and use.

```
#config/initializers/active_admin.rb

ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.before_filter do
    $current_admin_user = current_admin_user
  end
end
```

Comment: and what did you do?